# How to update ResultSet in Sqlite in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, resultset

I want to update my ResultSet with using SQLite in Java. When i am trying to update the Resultset it is giving me an exception : `java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver`. i have also done :

```
stmt = c.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

but still getting the exception, i think it is because we cannot update the result Set using SQLite DB. Please help that how can i update the Sqlite Resultset in java.

Comment: You cannot. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @CL What i want to do is fetching record from DB and now suppose getting 'A' or 'D' in result for a colomn -  "status".Now i want to show active if A or Deactive if D as result

Comment: The error clearly says "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver". The JDBC feature you are trying to use is simply not available in that driver. Also note that updateable result sets write the changes back to the database. It is not for changing column values for display purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get different values than those actually stored in the database, you can do these changes in the SQL query itself.
In the most general case, you can use a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```sql
SELECT ID,
       Name,
       [...],
       CASE Status
         WHEN 'A' THEN 'active'
         WHEN 'D' THEN 'inactive'
         ELSE          'whatever'
       END AS Status
FROM MyTable
```